# How can I add rows with same string value in specific columns and do not transform the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

i have tried to make this df to the on after the line
What i have

```
   Name    Id  Value_X  Value_Y   
0   Alex   34  1.1    2.5   
1   Julo   26  1.7    2.4   
2   Alex   34  0.9    0.5

pd.pivot_table(df, index=['Name','Id'],values=['Value_X','Value_Y'],aggfunc='sum')
```

But what i want:

```
   Name    Id  Value_X  Value_Y   
0   Alex   34  2.0    3.0   
1   Julo   26  1.7    2.4
```

I used `.groupby()` but it always adds on Index the Name and the Id ('Alex','Id') but i want the dataframe without modifications on its columns.

Comment: Did you just want to add a `.reset_index()` ?

Comment: Or - perhaps better... `df.groupby(['Name', 'Id'], as_index=False).sum()` ?

Comment: No need pivot just do groupby + sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need `reset_index()` along with groupby

```
df.groupby(['Name','Id'])['Value_X','Value_Y'].sum().reset_index()
```

or `as_index=False`

```
df.groupby(['Name','Id'],as_index = False)['Value_X','Value_Y'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this way:
if you want the columns of your choice

```
df.groupby(['Name','Age'])['Value_X','Value_Y'].sum()
```